# Insertar explicitamente un dato un campo de tipo IDENTITY

Tags: c#

Cordial saludo. En la actualidad tenemos una novedad al intentar insertar datos a una tabla, particularmente con el campo denominado REGISTRO. El campo REGISTRO en la tabla es del tipo INT IDENTITY, lo que implica que no puede recibir dato explicitamente. Estuvimos investiganado y encontramos esta solucion, la cual indicaba agregar una linea de codigo al modelo de la tabla así:

```
public class LlanHistoria
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public decimal Odometro { get; set; }
    public string? operacion { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_2 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_3 { get; set; }
    public decimal presion { get; set; }
    public int salida { get; set; }
    public string? estado { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
    public string? observaciones { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
}
```

Como pueden notar, la linea que agregamos fue esta: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]

Luego de hacer los modificaciones, procedimos a probar si el código funcionaba, por lo cual realizamos debug, encontrando nuevamente el mismo error, el cual dice:

```
System.AggregateException: 'Se han producido uno o varios errores.'
ApiException: The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (500).

ApiException: The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (500).
```

Status: 500
Response:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'LlanHistoria' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException e

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
```

Agradecemos las indicaciones que puedan brindarnos para poder registrar el dato explicitamente.

Comment: No tengo ni idea como solucionar tu problema.. pero si el campo es identity y queres meterle un dato a mano, algo me huele muy mal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El propio mensaje de error te lo dice:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table
> 'LlanHistoria' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

O sea que tienes que poner IDENTITY_INSERT a ON antes de insertar filas a la tabla ejecutando la siguiente instrucción SQL:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT LlanHistoria ON
```

Aquí tienes la documentación oficial de esta instrucción

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Como veo que al final el problema no es insertar explícitamente un dato en una columna de tipo IDENTITY, sino que el problema es usar correctamente IDENTITY. Tienes dos opciones:

En el `OnModelCreating` de tu clase DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LlanHistoria>()
        .Property(e => e.Registro)
        .UseIdentityColumn(); // Configura la columna como IDENTITY
}
```

Por medio de atributos, por ejemplo:

```
public class LlanHistoria
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    // Otras propiedades...
}
```

Comment: Hola Jesús, sabes como se hace esto que indicas desde c#?

Comment: Intente desde C# agregando estas linea context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.LlanHistoria ON"); la cual debe ir antes de context.SaveChanges(); pero apesar de ello, al hacer el debug, continua el error.

Comment: Hay varias maneras, pero yo buscaría como hacerlo usando EF Core que es lo que usas tú. https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#executing-non-querying-sql

Comment: Si continúa el error es porque ExecuteSqlRaw abre y cierra la conexión. La conexión debe quedarse abierta y seguir abierta cuando se hace la insercion. Son cosas de EF core, del cual no tengo mucho conocimiento porque no me gusta. Lo abandoné al principio cuando salió  en el 2009 y desarrollé mi propio ORM: EntityLite

Comment: Mira este post, a lo mejor te ayuda. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810685/custom-connection-opening-closing-for-dbcontext

Comment: Si no, tienes otras opciones como usar directamente SqlConnection y SqlCommand. O también SqlBulkCopy que es muy eficiente en la carga masiva y con el que se puede especificar que se deshabilite el IDENTITY INSERT

Comment: Según la documentación https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management?redirectedfrom=MSDN#behavior-in-ef6-and-future-versions-1. Lo único que necesitas hacer es llamar a `context.Database.Connection.Open();` antes del `ExecuteSqlRaw` y seguidamente hacer la inserción usando el mismo contexto. Pero vamos que no quiero saber nada de EF

Comment: Aun no logramos que funcione, este es el orden que estamos utilizando: context.Database.Connection.Open(); context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.LlanHistoria ON");  context.LlanHistoria.Add(q1); context.SaveChanges(); context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.LlanHistoria OFF"); Nos esta apareciendo con un error Connection.Open() aparece el error C1061 DatabaseFacade does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and not accessible extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing using directive...

Comment: Es importante mencionar que mi deseo en un principio no fue insertar datos explicitamente para el campo Registro, sino que mi deseo es que la propiedad IDENTYTI funcionara correctamente, pero cuando el usuario da insertar en el aplicativo, sale el error de que dicho dato no puede insertarse explicitamente, ya que al no mencionar un dato desde el usuario, el sistema automaticamente le pone el valor cero, fue por ello que me involucre en ingresarlo explicitamente. Si existe alguna forma de hacerlo funcionar, les agradecemos, pues en esencia, nos interese que funcione como IDENTYTI

Comment: Entonces deberías haber preguntado ¿Cómo se hace para que funcione correctamente lo del IDENTITY?, en vez de preguntar ¿Cómo insertar explicitamente un dato un campo de tipo IDENTITY? O sea un problema XY. Tienes un problema X, pero en vez de preguntar por ese problema X, preguntas como implementar la solución que has pensado Y

Comment: Por cierto, se te ha olvidado poner la clave primaria en el modelo